# ServicePrincipalsClient.BaseClient.Post(): unexpected status 403 with OData error

Tags: terraform

I am desperately looking for a solution,

I am getting this error message when I apply to terraform config file. Tried all the possible solution, but still getting it, can you please advice? Here is the tf file.

```
# Create Azure AD App Registration
resource "azuread_application" "app" {
  display_name = "my-app"
  owners       = [local.current_user_id]

}

# Create Service Principal
resource "azuread_service_principal" "app" {
  application_id               = azuread_application.app.application_id
  app_role_assignment_required = true
  owners                       = [local.current_user_id]
 
}

# Create Service Principal password
resource "azuread_service_principal_password" "app" {
  service_principal_id = azuread_service_principal.app.id
}

# Sleep for 300 seconds to allow for propagation
# of the Service Principal creation before attempting
# to create the AKS cluster.
resource "time_sleep" "wait_300_seconds" {
  create_duration = "300s"

  depends_on = [azuread_service_principal_password.app]
}

# Output the Service Principal and password
output "sp" {
  value     = azuread_service_principal.app.id
  sensitive = true
}

output "sp_password" {
  value     = azuread_service_principal_password.app.value
  sensitive = true
}
```

Comment: Continuing from the above ask, I am getting the below error when I do terraform Apply.

Error: Could not create service principal
│
│   with azuread_service_principal.app,
│   on sp.tf line 9, in resource "azuread_service_principal" "app":
│    9: resource "azuread_service_principal" "app" {
│
│ ServicePrincipalsClient.BaseClient.Post(): unexpected status 403 with OData error: Authorization_RequestDenied: When using this permission, the 
│ backing application of the service principal being created must in the local tenant

Comment: After Successful terraform plan, I am getting the error as below in Terraform apply
    
        *Error: Could not create service principal
    
        with azuread_service_principal.app,
        on sp.tf line 9, in resource "azuread_service_principal" "app":
        9: resource "azuread_service_principal" "app" {
    
        ServicePrincipalsClient.BaseClient.Post(): unexpected status 403 
        with OData error: Authorization_RequestDenied: When using this 
        permission, the nbacking application of the service principal being created must in the local tenant*